# Vbscript to increase width of embedded file icon in word document

Tags: file, vbscript, icons, embed

I am trying to insert an HTML file as icon in Word document using Vbscript. I have used the below mentioned code:

```
objSelection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject "", path & "\HTML Results\Summary.html", _
  False, True, "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", 1, _
  "ART Beta Master Datasheet_BETA_xxxx.html"
```

The code is working, but the icon name is not appearing completely as shown in the below image.
I want a code to increase the width of the icon so that the entire icon name is visible.

[image]